# Assigning points to each radio button selected

Tags: android, radio-button

I am currently developing a questionnaire based application where by there are  options. I need to assign numerical values to each radio button so when one of it is selected it will give a certain amount of points which will then be used to produce a cumulative amount. I need help in coding the java to do this. any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
int score = 0;
public TextView tv;

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch (view.getID()) {
        case R.id.radioButton1:
            if(checked)
                score +=1;
            break;

        case R.id.radioButton2:
            if(checked)
                score +=1;
            break;

        case R.id.radioButton3:
            if(checked)
                score +=3;
            break;
    }
}

public void updateScore(int score) {
    tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textview1);
    tv.setText(" " + score);
}
```

in the XML I have coded a textview with "0" and a text id of `@+id/textview1`

the issue is that the score remains at 0 even if any radio buttons are selected

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this?

Comment: @AjilO. I tried using                                                        
 int score = 0                                                                    
boolean(checked) = (RadioButton) view). isChecked(); switch(view.getId()) {                                                                                              case R.id.radioButton;                                                                                           if (checked)                                                                                                              score +=1;

Comment: Add code to show what you have tried so far, and how the result was different from what you require/expect.

Comment: I just updated my question to show you my code. thanks a bunch! @AjilO.

Comment: You need to call `updateScore` right after your `switch` statement. From the posted code it doesn't appear like you are calling the `updateScore` method anywhere :)

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a life saver. :) But I just tried calling the method and the score remains 0. Sorry I am really new at this. @AjilO.

Comment: Have you checked the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45736387/6891637) posted below? I tried that and it works. I have added some commented text to help you figure out what and where you have to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following changes to your code

```
public TextView tv;
int score = 0;

public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    switch (view.getId()) {   
        case R.id.radioButton1:
            if (checked) {
                score += 1;
            }
            break;

        case R.id.radioButton2:
            if(checked)
                score +=1;
            break;

        case R.id.radioButton3:
            if(checked)
                score +=3;
            break;
    }
    updateScore(score);  // <- Added this line here
}

public void updateScore(int score) {
    // Don't initialise your view here. Take it to onCreate()
    tv.setText(" " + score);
}
```

**EDIT**

Is your XML for the radio button similar to what I have here?

```
<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="asas"
    android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"/>
```

Make sure you have added the `android:onClick="onRadioButtonClicked"` property to each of the radio buttons

Comment: well I did the exact same thing but the score still remains 0. and when I try to add the onclick method to each radio button it doesnt allow me to click on it and my app crashes on my phone. but when I tried adding the onclick property to the radiogroup the app doesn't crash and I can select a radiobutton.